# Eclipse 2022-06 (4.24.0) does not recognise Java 17

Tags: eclipse, java-17

I want to move to Java-17, from Java-11.
Updated Eclipse to 2022-06 (4.24.0).
Eclipse clearly says that Java-17 is the selected JRE.
Entered an example with Text Blocks to test Java-17 features.

Eclipse says: "The Java feature 'Text Blocks' is only available with source level 15 and above"

Eclipse advises:

Set project compiler compliance settings to 15
Set project JRE build path entry to 'JavaSE-15'

In Windows/Settings everything shows v17.

In desperation I removed all other Java version from my Windows machine. Didn't help.

In the terminal window of Eclipse I CAN compile and run the TextBlock example, so JRE-17 is correct. It is that Eclipse seem to be unable to handle JRE-17.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about the *project's* own Properties dialog's Compiler Compliance page? Did you update the version of Java on the project's Java Build Path to be Java 17, and not Java 15?

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem! It was project specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is referring to the *project's* own Properties dialog's Compiler Compliance page. Projects can, and often do, override the workspace's settings so that they're retained in source control.